# Remove JButtons after I have created them in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, jbutton

How can I remove `JButton` objects after I have created them in a for loop?

I have created button objects in a for loop and I would like to remove them
afterwards, but is that possible?

I have the following algorithm:

```
For each one of the elements in the ArrayList
    Create a JButton(text) , where text is the current value for the specific element
    add it to the GridLayout
```

Java sample code:

```
ArrayList AL;
for(int  i = 0; i < AL.size() - 1 ; i++) {
    JButton JB = new JButton(get(i)); //add the text in JButton
    grid.add(JB);
    }
```

How can I remove them afterwards?
Since I'm creating them on the fly, is it possible to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove them later by storing the `JButton` references in an array. Just traverse that array or list and remove the entries.

Comment: It worked cause I created an ArrayList<JButton> list = new ArrayList<JButton>(),I stored the object references and afterwards i traversed the array and i removed the entries.thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can either scan through the children of the object you added them to and remove them there or you can keep a list of them when you create them and then scan through the list to delete them.